# Failed to compile when rendering ItemList

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render an ItemList and not sure why react doesn't like my code here. It says:

[image]

This is my List Component code:

```
class RecipeList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      recipes: [{
          url: 'http://via.placeholder.com/300x300',
          title: '1st Title',
          description: 'some decription 1'
        },{
          url: 'http://via.placeholder.com/300x300',
          title: '2nd Title',
          description: 'some decription 2'
        },{
          url: 'http://via.placeholder.com/300x300',
          title: '3rd Title',
          description: 'some decription 3'
      }]
    }
  }

  const Items = recipes.map((recipe, index) => {
    return <RecipeListItem
            key={index}
            recipe={recipe}
          />
  });
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {Items}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}

export default RecipeList;
```

I'm creating some sample data, then iterating through assigning the result to const Item.

Comment: Yeah check out what Austin said, but on top of that, you should never use the index as a key in a list. You'd be better off using something like `recipe.title`. That helps React figure out what has been update when changes happen. Otherwise, it'll need to rerender everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing your `render` function:

```
class RecipeList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      recipes: [{
          url: 'http://via.placeholder.com/300x300',
          title: '1st Title',
          description: 'some decription 1'
        },{
          url: 'http://via.placeholder.com/300x300',
          title: '2nd Title',
          description: 'some decription 2'
        },{
          url: 'http://via.placeholder.com/300x300',
          title: '3rd Title',
          description: 'some decription 3'
      }]
    }
  }

  render() {
    const Items = this.state.recipes.map((recipe, index) => {
      return (
        <RecipeListItem
          key={index}
          recipe={recipe}
        />
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {Items}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RecipeList;
```

also your map should loop through `this.state.recipes` instead of just `recipes`.

Comment: That's the perfect answer!